# How to populate a dictionary <key:value> when key is integer and value is Array<String>? SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array, dictionary and user

```
var dictionary = [Int:[String]]()
var tempArray = ["calls","messages","alerts","notifications"]
userId = 1
```

I want to add this array in a dictionary with against a key value which is userId(Int). The userId is incremented in a loop.e.g If I need the data of `userId = 5` then I can get the value of `tempArray` against the key `5`. Please help me how to save array against the `Int` key in dictionary.

Comment: Please show your desired result. Also note that your current code does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there in your example.  The main problem you had was that you mixed up defining and assigning the dictionary (easily and often done!)

Rather than

```
var dictionary = [Int,[String]]
```

You want to do either:

```
var dictionary: [Int:[String]]
```

which defines it, and then requires initialisation at a later point.  Note the use of the colon rather than comma to separate the key and value in the dictionary, as well as the colon used for the definition.

or

```
var dictionary: [Int:[String]] = [:]
```

which defines and initialises it in one, starting off with an empty dictionary.

Then you can assign the values you wanted by

```
dictionary[userId] = tempArray
```